# Earthreaver Stompers (Boots) Daily Power Target Clarification

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, powers

To the point:  Does the Daily Power given from the Earthreaver Stompers (AV) attack each creature in the burst, each enemy in the burst, or one creature in the burst?

"Power (Daily): Standard Action. You stomp your foot and
make an attack: Close burst 2; Strength + 4 vs. Reflex; on
a hit, the target is knocked prone."

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! *Great* first question, especially on your first exchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This power, as written is unclear.

Generally powers like this will specify two things.

- whether they target creatures or enemies (or allies)
- whether they target all creatures in the burst or a single creature.

This one does not specify *either* of those things. That means that it's up to your DM to interpret the intent of the power. There is a case to be made that it's a single target power (the singular use of "power"), but I'm pretty sure targets are referred to in the singular in multi target powers other places.

Given that it's a daily, standard action, item power. It's by no means out of bounds to take the broadest interpretation and say it targets all enemies in the burst.

Comment: The parts that confused me were "the target," meaning the creature hit by the attack which assumes one target in the burst, but also "on a hit," which could mean if any creature in the burst is hit.  It's pretty open-ended and I can't find any errata anywhere (not even in the rules compendium, and of course using DDI tools the power is stated exactly the same as in the book).

So what you're suggesting is let the DM decide?  Which personally I think would be fine, I was just curious if it was more specific than I had read.

Comment: Yeah, and it seems WOTC took down their per book FAQ (But I don't remember a clarification to this power, and since it wasn't errata'd there probably wasn't one). You've hit on *one* of the several problems in the power text. There's unfortunately no much clarity to be gained from other sources here :(

Comment: +1, I looked over the relevant rules, and they sort of imply that bursts normally hit everything in them, but I agree it doesn't explicitly say that. It explicitly says the power will indicate its targets. I always interpret these in the broadest possible manner, which is that it hits all creatures, not just enemies. Hitting just enemies, just allies, or just a single target would all be more specific exceptions.